# Convert excel row into txt file and insert it to DB2 in python

Tags: python, mysql, excel, db2

Hello masters of Python

What I am trying to achive: I want to load data from xlsx file in to database **(DB2 - connector)**. To do this I want to convert data from **xlsx to txt** file:
.txt - with inserts (e.g: insert into `test.aaa` values ('1', 'AA' , to_date ('2017-05-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), -1, '99');
When I will have this file I can send inserts into **DB2**.

For now what I am doing is to going through each cell in exel file and **append** it into txt file (using 'for' loops):

```
def modify(self):
    a = 0
    for i in range(self.sh.nrows):
        print(self.sh.row_values(a))
        b=0
        for i in range(self.sh.ncols):
            print(self.sh.cell_value(a,b))
            b += 1
        a += 1
```

Questions:
1) Is there any easer way to do this? Maybe I can create patter pass only whole row, not each cell?
2) Do you know if there is any library just to pass data from excel to database directly

Thanks

ps. if you see any mistakes in my code please feel free to correct me.

Sample data:

```
a   b   c   d
aaa 2017-11-12  111 0
bbb 2017-11-12  222 0
ccc 2017-11-12  333 0
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how the excel file looks like? does the excel file contain the data or just SQL queries?

Comment: Excel contain only data (no SQL queries) -Sample data added into description

Comment: `a` and `b` are not required at all. Simply use `rowy` instead of `i` for your first `for` loop, and `colx` for you `i` in your second `for` loop.

Comment: Alright, I would definitely advise you to use "Pandas" modules functionality, especially: "read_excel" and "to_sql" methods.

Comment: "to_sql" it will generate inserts?

Comment: I am trying to use pandas but I get this error:
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_excel'
e: it works now - I was using pandas.py :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help. Final version of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:1234@localhost/world') #create engine
conn = engine.connect() #open connection
df = pd.read_excel('ex1.xlsx', sheet_name = 'PM1', dtype = str) #create data_frame

df.to_sql('test1',conn,if_exists='append',index=False) #INSERT into DB
data = pd.read_sql('select * from test1',conn)

print(data)
```

There is only one thing: why I need use this: pymysql(engine). Without that code doesn't work. It requires me to add 'import pymysql'.